# How to deploy nodejs expressjs app in Azure with CI/CD?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs with expressjs app. My pipeline is this:

[image]

This create a correct artifact:

[image]

We can check here:

[image]

Now I create this release that uses the artifact I mentioned previously:

[image]

The steps in release:

[image]

And after release executed(success) in appname.scm.azurewebsites.net in wwwroot folder I have the right files:

[image]
But application never start because I never tell how start I think.

What would I put in Post deployment action? node server/server.js? (server.js is in server folder), npm start? In my package.json if I use npm start, then it going to run node server/server.js. Because in local, if I will run my app I have to execute npm start or node server/server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `package.json` file, normally you set the main file, `"main": "server.js"`, in your case I think you should define main as `"main": "server.js"` and move the server.js file from the server directory to project `root directory`.

If you look at the log stream, normally to start the project, azure runs `node server` or something you defined in the `package.json` as main.

I  have pasted  some parts of the azure log stream here so you can see what happens in the azure:

```
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222521897Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222528898Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222535898Z
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222542298Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222548498Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222554799Z      export PORT=8080
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222561899Z fi
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222783509Z
2022-05-09T18:19:04.222805710Z node server.js
```